# How to make Openfire Server Public from localhost

Tags: android, localhost, xmpp, openfire

I always use localhost to test my application on Openfire server, what is the process of accessing server from somewhere else what if i want to make it a public server, so that people can use my application from anywhere.

I am beginner please mention complete steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the DNS name of the server machine. Localhost is a purely local networking interface that is not accessible from other computers.